# Find $\int_1^3 \frac{\ln x}{x^2 + 3} dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to find the integral:

$$\int_1^3 \dfrac{\ln x}{x^2 + 3} dx$$

I tried integration by parts, but I can't find the next necessary integral, that being:

$$\int_1^3 \dfrac {\arctan (x/\sqrt3)}{x}$$

So I thought that maybe integration by parts is not the way to go. But I can't come with any solution.

Comment: You "tried integrating by parts."  Okay.  Which parts?  Can you please edit your question to show the details of your failed computation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integral $\int_1^3 \frac{\log x}{x^2+3}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798955/integral-int-13-frac-log-xx23dx)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798955/integral-int-13-frac-log-xx23dx?rq=1

Comment: It's been a while since I asked that linked question and I must say, at that time I was completely lost too. That substitution works, but perhaps a more intuitive approach would be to write:
$$\int_1^3 \frac{\ln x}{x^2+3}dx\overset{x=\sqrt 3 t}=\sqrt 3\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}^\sqrt 3 \frac{\ln(\sqrt 3)+\ln t}{3(t^2+1)}dt=\frac{\ln 3}{2\sqrt 3}\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}^\sqrt 3\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt+\frac1{\sqrt 3}\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}^\sqrt 3 \frac{\ln t}{t^2+1}dt$$
And now the latter integral vanishes with the substitution $t=\frac{1}{x}$ which I think is more obvious to use.

Comment: As an alternative to the latter vanishing integral, one can also write:
$$I=\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}^\sqrt 3 \frac{\ln t}{t^2+1}dt\overset{t=\tan x}=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^\frac{\pi}{3}\ln(\tan x)dx$$
And now via the substitution $x\to \frac{\pi}{2}−x$, or one might now this substitution as using
$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$ we get $I=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^\frac{\pi}{3}\ln(\tan x)dx=-\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^\frac{\pi}{3}\ln(\tan x)dx=0$. Hopefully this gives some intuition behind the symmetry.